# How to tell Facebook users don't be afraid to sign in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-connect

I'm working on a website that only accepts Facebook on their sign. I want to tell my users that we won't post anything on their name or like something that they don't, it's just the sign in proccess.
Bellow the sign in button we have a "No information will be published", since it's a online coaching website. But I want something even more reliable to our visitors.

I've found many ideas on web, but most of them tell about not sharing e-mail information. Do you have an idea to help me elaborate this privacy statement?

Comment: For those that are concerned about this, the only real solution is to offer options other than Facebook sign in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "I want something even more reliable to our visitors."

Then don't force the user to use Facebook to log in. Whenever I see that, I hit the back button. period. If I have options, I'll stick around.

If you MUST use Facebook's login API, ask for the least amount of permissions possible. No, you don't need access to everything. No, you don't need to post on my behalf. Just log me in to your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paul. In this case I MUST use Facebook's login API, do you think that if I specify something like "Only for login purposes. We will never post on your behalf." it'll be more convincent?

Comment: You're welcome. It might help. It just depends on the individual user. You'll need to identify their objection first.

Comment: I'll try acting as Lean UX suggests, I'll assume the hypothesis that my visitants go away because they're afraid that my site will post their confidential coaching information on their behalf. Test and see if the conversion rate increases after that update.
Do you think it's valid?

Comment: I'd say that's a good place to start. Good luck!

Comment: ++ x lots to this answer. Facebook only login == I don't use the site.

Comment: @Patrick: If you're truly only using Facebook for login, then why on earth *must* you use the FB API?